# Javascript loops

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have an array in javascript with following data to be populated in the divs. The array is as follows

```
var array1 = new array('abc','def', 'ghi', 'jkl','mno');
```

I want to implement pagination for a div containing set of divs holding each with data of above array. i.e., div 1 will contain abc, div 2 will contain def and so on...

I am sending the page no clicked and maximum number of divs to be displayed in a page to a function. I am setting max_num of divs to be displayed is 2. The function is as follows.

```
function renderPagination(pageno, max_num){
    for(var i=0;i< max_num; i++){
   }
}
```

Here i have to run a loop where the set of divs to be populated. i.e. if pageno is '0', the abc, def divs should get seen. If pageno is '1', the ghi, jkl divs should get rendered. I think instead of i=0, I have to initialize to other variable.

Answer (score 7):

Please use [Array.Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
function renderPagination(pageno, max_num) {
    return array1.slice( (pageno - 1) * max_num, pageno * max_num );
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/Ctp99/

On an unrelated side-note, the `Array` declaration should be `new Array()` and not <strike>`new array()`</strike>

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to initialise i, I believe you mean:

```
for(var i=pageno*max_num;i< max_num; i++){
}
```

Assuming pageno starts on 0, as per your text.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = ['abc','def', 'ghi', 'jkl','mno'];

function renderPagination(pageno, max_num){
    max_num += pageno; // max_num will be max_num + pageno

    // make sure max_num will not go out of bounds
    if(max_num > array1.length){
        max_num = array1.length;
    }

    for(pageno; pageno < max_num; pageno++){
        console.log(array1[pageno]);
    }
}
renderPagination(1, 2);
```

[**See a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/52JKE/)

With this solution, no matter where your page will start or what the `max_num` will be, it will always return the correct pages, and it will never go out of array bounds.

Comment: But on passing pageno as 2 the values are coming as def and ghi instead of ghi and jkl

Comment: @Bhaskar: Will your pages start from `0` or `1`? I wrote the code so pages could start from `1`, because that's how they normally do.

Comment: The pages are starting from 0

Comment: @Bhaskar: Okay, I updated the code. You can [check out the demo again](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/52JKE/).