# Split an array with sub arrays into separate arrays if the line count exceed $x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an [array of example data](http://pastebin.com/hqVmcw42) that i'm trying to split into two columns then paginate over the data.

Basically, i'm building a directory listing and need to display two columns of data.

If the data is too long for page one, it will split the data into another array and display it on another page.

The directory listing shows `tenantName` and `suiteNumber` on one line then if `includeOccupants` = Y, it will list the `occupant` array below the tenantName.

The problem comes in when displaying this data. I can only have 18 total rows in each column, so if there are 22 occupants, the list needs to break and show on the next column. I've hacked together a few solutions but nothing worth posting as an example.

My general thinking is that I should iterate over the list using a for loop and inside that for loop, iterate over the occupants array. Using a counter, increment the counter for every tenant and occupant and if that number gets to be bigger than 18, break the loop. My issue is with creating the second, 3rd, and possibly 4th arrays of data based on the supplied array of tenants.

```
var DIRECTORY_DATA = '[{"tenantName":"U.S. Trust","suiteNumber":201,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":2},{"tenantName":"Bank of America","suiteNumber":201,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":2},{"tenantName":"UBS Financial Services","suiteNumber":250,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":2},{"tenantName":"Summit Advisory Group","suiteNumber":300,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Beechler Tomberlin, PLLC.","suiteNumber":305,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"ProfitStarts, A Jack Henry Company","suiteNumber":310,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Nagle & Associates","suiteNumber":320,"occupants":["Carl B. Nagel","Tom Williams","Kenneth Allen","E. Lee Hicks, Jr.","Thomas R. Gladden, Jr.","David Carr"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Reginald F. Combs, P.C.","suiteNumber":330,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"MetLife","suiteNumber":340,"occupants":["","Bridges Wealth Management","Creative Group Management"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Baird Private Wealth Management","suiteNumber":350,"occupants":["","Jon Bolton","Steve Rowell","Scott Wray","Jeff Trollinger","Karver Bolton"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Novant Asset Management Company","suiteNumber":400,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Movement Mortgage LLC","suiteNumber":410,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Merrill Lynch","suiteNumber":430,"occupants":["Matthew Bee","Berverly Burke, CRPC ®","Christy Campbell","Todd H. Chase","Forrest C. Childers, CFP®","Kelly Dwyer","Michael E. Forsyth, CRPC®","Vance L. Horner II, CFA","Robert Hunt","Carlyle Kinlaw. CFA","Brett C. Ledgerwood","Vicky Leonard","Robert P. Maltzahn","Lucia J. Marshall, CFP®","Adolfo John (A.J.) Montesa II, CRPC®","Nathan A. Moser","David L. Neugent, CFP®","J. Keith Norman, CIMA®, CFP®","Elias H. Pegram, Jr.","Lorie Pilon","Brad Pitts, CFP®","E. Lee Raymer","John C. Setzer, Residnet Direcotr","JoBeth P. Souza, CRPC®","William C. Taylor","Marcia Turnage","Tammy Watts-Quesinberry","Robert P. Whaling, Jr. ","Scott K. Young, CRP®"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Baird Institutional Fixed Income","suiteNumber":440,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Metcalf & Beal, Attorneys at Law","suiteNumber":450,"occupants":["W. Eugene Metcalf","Christopher L. Beal","Lauren M. Vocci"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Iri","suiteNumber":460,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Nelson, Mullins, Riley, Scarborough, LLP. Attorneys at Law","suiteNumber":530,"occupants":["Cassie L. Crawford","Candace S. Friel","Denise M. Gunter","Donald R. Pocock","Mark A. Stafford"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":5},{"tenantName":"Oppenheimer & Co., Inc. ","suiteNumber":560,"occupants":["","William P. Greathouse, Jr. ","Tanner G. Robinson","Gregory Scotiniadis","Eugene Gray Smith","Jerry E. Smith"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":5},{"tenantName":"Bowen, Hanes & Company, Inc.","suiteNumber":570,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":5},{"tenantName":"Wells Fargo Advisors","suiteNumber":600,"occupants":["Alex Galloway","Allen Gillespie","Cyndi Gross","Clay Canady","Conrad Graham","Daniel Choplin","Danny Riazzi","Ed Irvin","Fronie Martin","Janet Sidden","Jim Kluttz","Joe Rhyne","John Bates","John Cox","John Martin","Keary Didier","Larry Hand","Mike Dowell ","Neal Robinson","Pat Crowley","Pat Riazzi","Paul Glenn","Robert Nichols","Scott Settelen","Stacy Dillion","Sterling Swaim","Tim Barnes","Todd Lynch","Tom Goodson","Wes Perry ","Will Goodson"],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"John W. Burress","suiteNumber":610,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Paul Fulton","suiteNumber":610,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Liipfert Law Group","suiteNumber":620,"occupants":["B. Bailey Liipfert, III","J. Benjamin Limehouse"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Wells Law, PLLC.","suiteNumber":640,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Goodson & Nichols Financial Group","suiteNumber":650,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Allman, Spry, Davis, Leggett & Crumpler P.A. Attorneys & Legal Counsel","suiteNumber":700,"occupants":["C. Edwin Allman, III","M. Joseph Allman","Kim R. Bonuomo","T. Terry Crumpler","Joslin Davis","Bernard M. Desrosiers","Jodi D. Hildebran","Scott T. Horn","George D. Humphrey, III","R. Bradford Leggett","Karen B. Malay","George T. Mann","Marsh Prause","Bennett Rainey","Edward E. Raymer","Kayla Sipprell","Donald VonCannon","Anna Warburton Munroe"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":7}]';

DIRECTORY_DATA = JSON.parse(DIRECTORY_DATA);

var tenant_count = DIRECTORY_DATA.length;

SORTED_DATA = DIRECTORY_DATA.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.suiteNumber - b.suiteNumber;
});


var line_total = 0;
var arrays = [];

var REMAINING_DATA = [];

for (var tenants in SORTED_DATA) {
    var tenant = SORTED_DATA[tenants];
    if (line_total >= 20) {
        break;
    } else {

        line_total++;
        array.push({'tenant':tenant.tenantName,'occupants':[]});

        if (tenant.includeOccupant === 'Y') {
            for (var occupants in tenant.occupants) {
                var occupant = tenant.occupants[occupants];
                if (line_total <= 20) {
                    array[tenants].occupants.push(occupant);
                    line_total++;
                } else {
                    REMAINING_DATA.push({'tenant':tenant.tenantName, 'occupants':[occupant]})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code above doesn't work because i'm pushing stuff to REMAINING_DATA incorrectly and quite frankly, i believe there is better ways to go about this whole thing -- which is why I really didn't want to post code as to not skew answers.

As for outcome of what i'm looking for.

If there are 20 tenants and two tenants have 10 occupants each, thats 40 total lines. Since I can only have 36 total lines.. The function should take the 40 total lines, and split it into two or more arrays while maintaining the tenant and occupant structure.

Comment: please add the data and the wanted outcome and the code you tried. please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: it's not right to paginate an array on client-side, data must be splitted on serverside and outputted for parsing. but as You insist on it, so take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037162/javascript-loops

Comment: @num8er this is wrong, if I load some static data into the client. And I have a dynamic table, which I can sort / paginate / filter on the client why is it not right?

Comment: I have the pagination working client side (its not actual pagination, its more of refreshing the DOM with remaining content from the array). This is really easy when not including the occupant array as part of the display. My problems start when I include the occupant array into the display as splitting that data is much harder for me.

Comment: this is very complex what you are doing, try it with `Array.slice`

Comment: @webdeb if You load a huge array to client-side application it will make browser lag (because of memory resources of client device). But You can get the huge array once on server-side and cache it, so in this case You can easily portion data to client.

Comment: @num8er I don't know what you mean with 'huge' how much is it in your case?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from @num8er however memory consumption and performance isn't an issue in this use case. It's a 100% client side application with a relatively small object of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

Here I'm doing filter to sort out unnecessary data.

Then doing map to make data formatted.

```js
var data = '[{"tenantName":"U.S. Trust","suiteNumber":201,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":2},{"tenantName":"Bank of America","suiteNumber":201,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":2},{"tenantName":"UBS Financial Services","suiteNumber":250,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":2},{"tenantName":"Summit Advisory Group","suiteNumber":300,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Beechler Tomberlin, PLLC.","suiteNumber":305,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"ProfitStarts, A Jack Henry Company","suiteNumber":310,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Nagle & Associates","suiteNumber":320,"occupants":["Carl B. Nagel","Tom Williams","Kenneth Allen","E. Lee Hicks, Jr.","Thomas R. Gladden, Jr.","David Carr"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Reginald F. Combs, P.C.","suiteNumber":330,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":3},{"tenantName":"MetLife","suiteNumber":340,"occupants":["","Bridges Wealth Management","Creative Group Management"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Baird Private Wealth Management","suiteNumber":350,"occupants":["","Jon Bolton","Steve Rowell","Scott Wray","Jeff Trollinger","Karver Bolton"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":3},{"tenantName":"Novant Asset Management Company","suiteNumber":400,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Movement Mortgage LLC","suiteNumber":410,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Merrill Lynch","suiteNumber":430,"occupants":["Matthew Bee","Berverly Burke, CRPC ®","Christy Campbell","Todd H. Chase","Forrest C. Childers, CFP®","Kelly Dwyer","Michael E. Forsyth, CRPC®","Vance L. Horner II, CFA","Robert Hunt","Carlyle Kinlaw. CFA","Brett C. Ledgerwood","Vicky Leonard","Robert P. Maltzahn","Lucia J. Marshall, CFP®","Adolfo John (A.J.) Montesa II, CRPC®","Nathan A. Moser","David L. Neugent, CFP®","J. Keith Norman, CIMA®, CFP®","Elias H. Pegram, Jr.","Lorie Pilon","Brad Pitts, CFP®","E. Lee Raymer","John C. Setzer, Residnet Direcotr","JoBeth P. Souza, CRPC®","William C. Taylor","Marcia Turnage","Tammy Watts-Quesinberry","Robert P. Whaling, Jr. ","Scott K. Young, CRP®"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Baird Institutional Fixed Income","suiteNumber":440,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Metcalf & Beal, Attorneys at Law","suiteNumber":450,"occupants":["W. Eugene Metcalf","Christopher L. Beal","Lauren M. Vocci"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Iri","suiteNumber":460,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":4},{"tenantName":"Nelson, Mullins, Riley, Scarborough, LLP. Attorneys at Law","suiteNumber":530,"occupants":["Cassie L. Crawford","Candace S. Friel","Denise M. Gunter","Donald R. Pocock","Mark A. Stafford"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":5},{"tenantName":"Oppenheimer & Co., Inc. ","suiteNumber":560,"occupants":["","William P. Greathouse, Jr. ","Tanner G. Robinson","Gregory Scotiniadis","Eugene Gray Smith","Jerry E. Smith"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":5},{"tenantName":"Bowen, Hanes & Company, Inc.","suiteNumber":570,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":5},{"tenantName":"Wells Fargo Advisors","suiteNumber":600,"occupants":["Alex Galloway","Allen Gillespie","Cyndi Gross","Clay Canady","Conrad Graham","Daniel Choplin","Danny Riazzi","Ed Irvin","Fronie Martin","Janet Sidden","Jim Kluttz","Joe Rhyne","John Bates","John Cox","John Martin","Keary Didier","Larry Hand","Mike Dowell ","Neal Robinson","Pat Crowley","Pat Riazzi","Paul Glenn","Robert Nichols","Scott Settelen","Stacy Dillion","Sterling Swaim","Tim Barnes","Todd Lynch","Tom Goodson","Wes Perry ","Will Goodson"],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"John W. Burress","suiteNumber":610,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Paul Fulton","suiteNumber":610,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Liipfert Law Group","suiteNumber":620,"occupants":["B. Bailey Liipfert, III","J. Benjamin Limehouse"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Wells Law, PLLC.","suiteNumber":640,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Goodson & Nichols Financial Group","suiteNumber":650,"occupants":[""],"includeOccupant":"","floor":6},{"tenantName":"Allman, Spry, Davis, Leggett & Crumpler P.A. Attorneys & Legal Counsel","suiteNumber":700,"occupants":["C. Edwin Allman, III","M. Joseph Allman","Kim R. Bonuomo","T. Terry Crumpler","Joslin Davis","Bernard M. Desrosiers","Jodi D. Hildebran","Scott T. Horn","George D. Humphrey, III","R. Bradford Leggett","Karen B. Malay","George T. Mann","Marsh Prause","Bennett Rainey","Edward E. Raymer","Kayla Sipprell","Donald VonCannon","Anna Warburton Munroe"],"includeOccupant":"Y","floor":7}]';

data = JSON.parse(data);
data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.suiteNumber - b.suiteNumber;
});

var tenantsOccupants = {};

data.forEach(function(item) {
  if(item.includeOccupant !== 'Y') {return;}

  if(!tenantsOccupants[item.tenantName]) {
    tenantsOccupants[item.tenantName] = [];
  }
  
  item.occupants.forEach(function(occupant) {
    tenantsOccupants[item.tenantName].push(occupant);
  });
});

console.log(tenantsOccupants);
```

Comment: where would the `occupants` array come into play here? What you have would work if there was no occupants array.  That is my current issue.

Comment: it's slicing function made to portion the data, it's not full code, it's an example of paginating the array. as @webdev said: try Array.slice()

Comment: i'm looking for a way to paginate data that has a subarray of data within it. Please see the array of data that im working with. It includes an `occupants` array and that is where my issue comes in. I'm having no issue iterating over the tenants, my problem is when I iterate over the tenants AND the subarray of tenant occupants.

Comment: @KFE, I see, so let me change my answer (:

Comment: @KFE I've changed answer, is that what You need?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dN9qOKd.png  - here is an example of the output. The left column would have a max of 18 lines. Once it hits 18 lines, it should break the array of TENANTS and OCCUPANTS and put the rest on the 2nd column (up to 18 lines). If there is still more tenants and occupants, it will take the remaining occupants and do the same thing again and again until the list is empty (client side pagination)

Comment: @KFE now You've tenantsOccupants object that has key => value structure. so to paginate occupants of one tenant so You only need to use Array.slice

Answer (score 0):

Its that simple:

define your settings, and create your pages.

I think the code is self explainable

```js
var array = [6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5];
array.sort()

var pages = [];
var page = 0;
var perPage = 3;
var currentIdx = 0;
while(true) {
  currentIdx = perPage * page;
  if (currentIdx >= array.length) break; 

  pages.push(
    array.slice(currentIdx, currentIdx + perPage)
  )
  
  page++;
}

console.log(pages)

// Get the occupants.. with suiteNumber 

var occupants = data.reduce(function(occupantsArray, item) {
  item.occupants.forEach(function(occupant) {
    occupant.suiteNumber = item.suiteNumber;
    occupantsArray.push(occupant)
  })
}, [])

occupants // [{suitNumber: xx, occupantsData..}, {}]
```

Comment: this looks good but what about a subarray? In your example, say `8` has a sub array of data [a,b,c,d] ... how would you include that array into the math?

Comment: this works, but it only takes the main arrays into account, it doesn't iterate over the secondary sub array of `occupants`. I'm looking for a way to slice the main array of tenants as well as the sub-array of occupants (if needed)

Comment: sorry, I couldn't read the data structure of your question, and did't recognized the sub arrays.. well then you should `flatten` the array, and then run that function..

Comment: nice, thanks! flattening an array definitely looks like a viable option. Is there a way to somewhat maintain the structure? Basically the main array is TENANTS and certain TENANTS have OCCUPANTS. I would need to know which TENANT the OCCUPANTS belong to.

Comment: you have several ways.. you can let the occupants inside the tentants and render them just in place under the tentants, or you could have some key assigned to them.. It shouldn't be a problem, but let discuss it in a new question. I'll take a look on it, when you add a link here.

Comment: @KFE in your case you could give every occupant the `suiteNumber` seams to be unique.. I'll add it in a minute

Comment: see my comment on the above answer (with the imgur link) for what i currently have and what i'm trying to accomplish. Your pagination is close but I need to count the occupants in this whole ordeal as well. I could've solved this problem by now if it didn't need the occupants as well. thank you for your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: check how you can get the occupants with relation to the tentants by the suiteNumber